# class: mysqli_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysqli

I followed the php.net's doc to get certain object's result from `fetch_object`,

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "tklau", "xx_2011");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "
    SELECT cnt_id, cnt_email1
    FROM root_contacts_cfm
    ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
    ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        print_r($obj);
        //echo $obj->cnt_email1;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

I will get this,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cnt_id] => 2
    [cnt_email1] => rocco@xx.net
)
stdClass Object
(
    [cnt_id] => 1
    [cnt_email1] => lola@xx.co.uk
)
```

But I want to make this code into a class instead,

```
#connects the database and handling the result
class __database {

    protected $connection = null;
    protected $error = null;

    #make a connection
    public function __construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database)
    {
        $this -> connection = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function fetch_object($query) 
    {
        $result = $this -> connection -> query($query);
        if($result) 
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                return $row;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            $this -> error = $this -> connection -> error;
            return false;
        }
    }


    #display error
    public function get_error() 
    {
        return $this -> error;
    }

    #closes the database connection when object is destroyed.
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this -> connection -> close();
    }
}
```

so, I will call the class function like this,

```
$sql = "
    SELECT cnt_id, cnt_email1
    FROM root_contacts_cfm
    ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
    ";

$items = $connection -> fetch_object($sql);
print_r($items);
```

but I get only one row from the result which is not correct,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cnt_id] => 2
    [cnt_email1] => lau@xx.net
)
```

it must be something wrong in my class function of `fetch_object` - how can I fix it? please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function is returning when it finds the first result.
    `return $row;`
You should store each row in an array and then return the array.

```
if($result){
   $function_result = array();
   $i = 0;
   while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
      $function_result[$i] = $row;
      $i++;
   }
  return $function_result;
}
```